# How to share a form via link in php laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, share

I am working a laravel project in which user can build any type of form by drag and drop. I have successfully made a form such as login form . Now I want to share my login form via a link.

Here my project image...
[image]

In the my project there are two side left and right side. Here user will create a form using left side tool by dragging and dropping in the right side part. Now I want user can send his form only via a link or embed his website .
How can solve the problem?

Comment: can use tag `iframe`

Answer (score 1):

Save the entire form structure html you create (the html that is rendered in the right side) into your database and create a link / route in laraveel which will fetch this html from the database and serve that as a response to the link.